# Flutter reverse clipper direction

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to show triangle type shape container which is almost complete but there is one issue its showing the triangle shape in opposite direction my code

```
class ClipPathClass extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    var roundnessFactor = 50.0;

    var path = Path();

    path.moveTo(0, size.height * 0.33);
    path.lineTo(0, size.height - roundnessFactor);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(0, size.height, roundnessFactor, size.height);
    path.lineTo(size.width - roundnessFactor, size.height);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(
        size.width, size.height, size.width, size.height - roundnessFactor);
    path.lineTo(size.width, roundnessFactor * 2);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(size.width - 10, roundnessFactor,
        size.width - roundnessFactor * 1.5, roundnessFactor * 1.5);
    path.lineTo(
        roundnessFactor * 0.6, size.height * 0.33 - roundnessFactor * 0.3);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(
        0, size.height * 0.33, 0, size.height * 0.33 + roundnessFactor);

    return path;
  }
  

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) => false;
}
```

This is how i am showing this

```
     ClipPath(
        clipper: RoundedDiagonalPathClipper(), 
        child: Container(
          height: 320,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(30.0)),
            color: Colors.orange,
          ),
          child: null,
        ),
      ),
```

Out put is showing like this

[image]

But i need to show the upper part like this just reverse it. I play with everything but it's not reversing.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I implemented `_getY` function so that there is no bend in the corner. And I added an `equalization` variable to make look better.

Reference: [Paths in Flutter: A Visual Guide](https://medium.com/flutter-community/paths-in-flutter-a-visual-guide-6c906464dcd0).

#### Screenshot

[image]

#### RoundedDiagonalPathClipper.dart

```dart
class RoundedDiagonalPathClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  double _getY(double x) {
    return x * 0.33;
  }

  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    var roundnessFactor = 50.0;
    var equalization = 10.0;
    var path = Path();

    path.moveTo(0, roundnessFactor);
    path.lineTo(0, size.height - roundnessFactor);

    path.quadraticBezierTo(0, size.height, roundnessFactor, size.height);
    path.lineTo(size.width - roundnessFactor, size.height);

    path.quadraticBezierTo(
        size.width, size.height, size.width, size.height - roundnessFactor);

    path.lineTo(size.width, _getY(size.width) + roundnessFactor - equalization);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(
        size.width,
        _getY(size.width),
        size.width - roundnessFactor + equalization,
        _getY(size.width - roundnessFactor + equalization));

    path.lineTo(
        roundnessFactor + equalization, _getY(roundnessFactor + equalization));
    path.quadraticBezierTo(0, 0, 0, roundnessFactor + equalization);

    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) => false;
}
```

#### Edit: Adding shadow

I made the shadow version by using the [gist:coman3-ClipShadowPath.dart](https://gist.github.com/coman3/e631fd55cd9cdf9bd4efe8ecfdbb85a7).

[image]

#### ClipShadowPath.dart

```dart
@immutable
class ClipShadowPath extends StatelessWidget {
  final Shadow shadow;
  final CustomClipper<Path> clipper;
  final Widget child;

  ClipShadowPath({
    required this.shadow,
    required this.clipper,
    required this.child,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CustomPaint(
      key: UniqueKey(),
      painter: _ClipShadowShadowPainter(
        clipper: this.clipper,
        shadow: this.shadow,
      ),
      child: ClipPath(child: child, clipper: this.clipper),
    );
  }
}

class _ClipShadowShadowPainter extends CustomPainter {
  final Shadow shadow;
  final CustomClipper<Path> clipper;

  _ClipShadowShadowPainter({required this.shadow, required this.clipper});

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    var paint = shadow.toPaint();
    var clipPath = clipper.getClip(size).shift(shadow.offset);
    canvas.drawPath(clipPath, paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

#### Usage

```dart
ClipShadowPath(
  shadow: Shadow(blurRadius: 20.0, color: Colors.black54),
  clipper: RoundedDiagonalPathClipper(),
  child: Container(color: Colors.orange),
)
```

Comment: For a moment I thought I wrote this answer. `Screenshot` > `Code` my signature headings.

Comment: Thanks for your answer can you tell how can i add shadow in this code please ?

Comment: @rameezkhan Sure, I added the code. I think you can easily implement this without me by searching google like "CustomClipper shadow in flutter" :)

Answer (score 1):

just apply Matrix transformation on Path, so you will free to do any changes on path, it will flip vertically any path

how to use:

```
clipper: ClipPathClass(),
```

or if need to reverse

```
clipper: ClipPathClass(flip: true),
```

```
class ClipPathClass extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  final roundnessFactor = 50.0;
  final bool flip;

  ClipPathClass({this.flip = false});

  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    final path = Path();
    path.moveTo(0, size.height * 0.33);
    path.lineTo(0, size.height - roundnessFactor);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(0, size.height, roundnessFactor, size.height);
    path.lineTo(size.width - roundnessFactor, size.height);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(size.width, size.height, size.width, size.height - roundnessFactor);
    path.lineTo(size.width, roundnessFactor * 2);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(size.width - 10, roundnessFactor, size.width - roundnessFactor * 1.5, roundnessFactor * 1.5);
    path.lineTo(roundnessFactor * 0.6, size.height * 0.33 - roundnessFactor * 0.3);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(0, size.height * 0.33, 0, size.height * 0.33 + roundnessFactor);
    return flip ? _flip(path, size.width) : path;
  }

  Path _flip(Path path, double width) {
    final m = Matrix4.identity()
      ..translate(width)
      ..rotateY(math.pi);
    return path.transform(m.storage);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) => false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I won't explain the change line by line, I tried to keep the round corner uniform on the four corners.

Here your are:

```
class RoundedDiagonalPathClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    var roundnessFactor = 50.0;

    var path = Path();

    path.moveTo(0, roundnessFactor);
    path.lineTo(0, size.height - roundnessFactor);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(0, size.height, roundnessFactor, size.height);
    path.lineTo(size.width - roundnessFactor, size.height);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(
        size.width, size.height, size.width, size.height - roundnessFactor);
    path.lineTo(size.width, size.height * 0.33 + roundnessFactor * 0.5);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(
        size.width,
        size.height * 0.33,
        size.width - roundnessFactor,
        size.height * 0.33 - roundnessFactor * 0.5);
    path.lineTo(roundnessFactor, 0);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(0, 0, 0, roundnessFactor);

    return path;
  }
```

The result will be this one:
[image]